# Adding two columns' data into one table but getting an infinite number of additions done instead

Tags: mysql

i know this question probably sounds similar as others but just bear with me.

What i'm aiming to do is to insert data from the five columns in the table test_data_merged(as expressed as t - t5 by aliases) as well as data from a column in location table; SIX columns in total, all into a table called prefinalyear_data which has SEVEN columns, one of which is a primary key that auto increments. Each table mentioned currently has only six rows of data keyed in first for convenience-sake.

The code i came up with is as shown:

**`INSERT INTO prefinalyear_data (test_date, student_name, test_id, class_ID, pass_score, fail_score)`**

```
SELECT s.test_date, s2.student_name, s3.test_id, location.class_ID, pass_score, fail_score  
FROM test_data_merged t, test_data_merged t2, test_data_merged t3, test_data_merged t4, test_data_merged t5, location;
```

Problem is, for some weird reason when i use the above code a very, very large number of repeated rows are added to the final table instead of just six!

NO error is reported but basically nothing useful is actually added to the final table.

Comment: mysql or`(MS)SQL-Server? do not use tags for products which are not involved

Comment: you Need to tell your query what to join the tables on.
and you really should use `JOIN` syntax

Answer (score 0):

You are secting from 6 tables without the Information how the data should be joined. So you get a [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product).

Use the correct `join` Syntax:

```
SELECT s.test_date, s2.student_name, s3.test_id, location.class_ID, pass_score, fail_score  
FROM test_data_merged t 
join test_data_merged t2 on ...
join test_data_merged t3 on ....
join test_data_merged t4 on ...
join test_data_merged t5 on ...
join Location on ...
```

read more about join on the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but could you explain what you meant by that? How should i modify the code to join the data? PS. nvm i just saw what you meant

Comment: @Mark I can not give you the join condition, because i do not know how the tables looks like and how they belpong together.

Comment: I'm still a little confused here. Because the two tables i am attempting to merge have no columns in common, hence i dont quite see how join can be used here.

Comment: @Mark As i said without more detailed informations (ddl and sample data) i can not help you more